# what is the phase portrait of this system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

what is the phase portrait of this system.

$$\begin{cases}
\dot x_1&=-x_1+x_2\\
\dot x_2&=-x_2
\end{cases}$$

**My work**

I have solved this, and I got the general solution as,
$$e^{\frac{x_1}{x_2}}=\frac c{x_2^2}$$

But I dont know how to sketch the phase portrait.

In some method i have the solution as,
$$\begin{cases}x_1=c(1+t)e^t\\
x_2=0\end{cases}$$ Here also i couldnt draw the phase portrait. Am I correct in my approach? What i have to keep in mind in solving such problems? And how I can confirm the directions of the curves?

Comment: See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/PhasePlane.aspx) on how to draw the phase portrait.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1010409/how-to-plot-a-phase-potrait-of-a-system-of-odes-in-mathematica/1010435#1010435) for Matlab and Mathematica code.

Comment: can't be try in free hand? that is, can't be guess the direction??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typing `streamplot -x+y,-y` in the dialog box of [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) yields this:

[image]

Comment: can't be try in free hand? that is, can't be guess the direction?

Comment: ?? No idea what you are talking about. Please rephrase.

Comment: am asking whether we can draw this by hand without using any software or not. That's by solving this system itself can we find the phase portrait?

Comment: The directions N, NE, E, SE, S, SW, W and NW, of the diagram are easy to compute by hand. But the full diagram with curves linking the arrows might require a software.